# What is the best lightweight alternative to VGG16 for image fingerprinting?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, computer-vision, image-recognition, vgg, template-matching

I am using a VGG16 model with the classification layer stripped off to generate vectors for an intermediate stage of an image fingerprinting algorithm.  It works well, but VGG16 is a little hefty, and I was wondering what suggestions the community had regarding good alternatives to VGG16, with regards to this application, if someone is looking for something lighter weight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for lightweights architecture, take a look at backbones designed for mobile such as [MobileNet V3](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.02244.pdf) or [GhostNet V2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2211.12905.pdf) .

Comment: also maybe EfficientNet

Comment: and also [ShuffleNet-V2](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_ECCV_2018/papers/Ningning_Light-weight_CNN_Architecture_ECCV_2018_paper.pdf)